# How to remove Black Rectangle box in Dialog?

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog

I used the following code to prepare an custom dialog,it is showing my custom layout in a black colored rectangle box.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getParent(),R.style.PauseDialog);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.social_share);
dialog.setTitle("Social Sharing");
dialog.setCancelable(true);
```

How to remove that box,which should show only my custom layout.

Thanks!

Comment: paste your code of style

Comment: <style name="PauseDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of what you want and what you are getting... This will give the clarity

Comment: I have an image but, I didnt have enough reputations

Answer (score 0):

You can set background with `<shape>` as per your requirement in your customize dialog

In **custom_dialog_layout.xml**:

```
android:background = "@layout/dialog_shape"
```

then in **dialog_shape.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle" > 
     <gradient android:startColor="#FF0E2E57" 
     android:endColor="#FF0E2E57" 
            android:angle="225" android:paddingLeft="20dip"/> 
</shape>
```

Comment: <style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>        
</style>

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);

Comment: can you tell what I need to add in transparent